# i7 Notebook with 4:3 or at least 16:10 screen?

Tags: intel-core-i7

I am sick and tired of my widescreen 16:9 MacBook (running mostly Windows anyway). Does anyone know any new (= i7, i5 CPU) notebook with a 15''-16'' inch screen in the 4:3 or at least 16:10 format?

Answer (score 1):

There are several, most of them Apple though (means the internal keyboard might not be what you expect and you need to bring your own Windows license).

I used [this german site](http://geizhals.at/deutschland/?cat=nb15w&xf=1200_16%3A10%7E1200_4%3A3%7E85_15%7E85_15.4%7E85_15.6%7E85_15.5%7E85_16%7E85_16.4%7E29_Core+i7%7E29_Core+i5), should give you an overview at least.

Comment: Thanks, useful site. But the many notebooks in that list that supposed to have 16:10 turn out to be 16:9 (like HP Pro). So they have the wrong tags.

Comment: You're right. So far the site has not disappointed me, I'm sorry about that. The MSI is 1680x1050 though.

Comment: The higher-end hp seems to be available as both 1366x768 and 1280x800 (one shop lists both variants).  This might add to the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of OEMs have had to move to 16:9 simply because it's getting hard to get 16:10 panels that are acceptably priced for inclusion in a laptop; about all you can find these days are higher end IPS panels, etc.  It's even worse with 4:3 displays, especially if you want something bigger than a netbook.

I know Lenovo still has a 14" 16:10 (ThinkPad T410).